# Can Spring-Data-Rest handle associations to Resources on other Microservices?

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

For a new project i'm building a rest api that references resources from a second service. For the sake of client convenience i want to add this association to be serialized as an _embedded entry.

Is this possible at all? i thought about building a fake CrudRepository (facade for a feign client) and manually change all urls for that fake resource with resource processors. would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a little deep dive into the functionality of spring-data-rest:

Data-Rest wraps all Entities into `PersistentEntityResource` Objects that extend the `Resource<T>` interface that spring HATEOAS provides. This particular implementation has a list of embedded objects that will be serialized as the `_embedded` field.

So in theory the solution to my problem should be as simple as implementing a `ResourceProcessor<Resource<MyType>>` and add my reference object to the embeds.

In practice this aproach has some ugly but solvable issues:

`PersistentEntityResource` is not generic, so while you can build a ResourceProcessor for it, that processor will by default catch everything. I am not sure what happens when you start using Projections. So that is not a solution.

`PersistentEntityResource` implements `Resource<Object>` and as a result can not be cast to `Resource<MyType>` and vice versa. If you want to to access the embedded field all casts have to be done with `PersistentEntityResource.class.cast()` and `Resource.class.cast()`.

Overall my solution is simple, effective and not very pretty. I hope Spring-Hateoas gets full fledged HAL support in the future.

Here my ResourceProcessor as a sample:

```
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<MyType>> typeProcessorToAddReference() {
    // DO NOT REPLACE WITH LAMBDA!!!
    return new ResourceProcessor<>() {
        @Override
        public Resource<MyType> process(Resource<MyType> resource) {

            try {
                // XXX all resources here are PersistentEntityResource instances, but they can't be cast normaly
                PersistentEntityResource halResource = PersistentEntityResource.class.cast(resource);

                List<EmbeddedWrapper> embedded = Lists.newArrayList(halResource.getEmbeddeds());
                ReferenceObject reference = spineClient.findReferenceById(resource.getContent().getReferenceId());
                embedded.add(embeddedWrappers.wrap(reference, "reference-relation"));

                // XXX all resources here are PersistentEntityResource instances, but they can't be cast normaly
                resource = Resource.class.cast(PersistentEntityResource.build(halResource.getContent(), halResource.getPersistentEntity())
                    .withEmbedded(embedded).withLinks(halResource.getLinks()).build());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Something went wrong", e);
                // swallow
            }
            return resource;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to work in type safe manner and with links only (addition references to custom controller methods), you can find inspiration in this sample code:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.RepresentationModelProcessor;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn;

@Configuration
public class MyTypeLinkConfiguration {
    public static class MyType {}

    @Bean
    public RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<MyType>> MyTypeProcessorAddLifecycleLinks(MyTypeLifecycleStates myTypeLifecycleStates) {
        // WARNING, no lambda can be passed here, because type is crucial for applying this bean processor.
        return new RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<MyType>>() {
            @Override
            public EntityModel<MyType> process(EntityModel<MyType> resource) {
                // add custom export link for single MyType
                myTypeLifecycleStates
                        .listReachableStates(resource.getContent().getState())
                        .forEach(reachableState -> {
                            try {
                                // for each possible next state, generate its relation which will get us to given state
                                switch (reachableState) {
                                    case DRAFT:
                                        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(MyTypeLifecycleController.class).requestRework(resource.getContent().getId(), null)).withRel("requestRework"));
                                        break;
                                    case IN_REVIEW:
                                        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(MyTypeLifecycleController.class).requestReview(resource.getContent().getId(), null)).withRel("requestReview"));
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        throw new RuntimeException("Link for target state " + reachableState + " is not implemented!");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                // swallowed
                                log.error("error while adding lifecycle link for target state " + reachableState + "! ex=" + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                            }
                        });
                return resource;
            }
        };
    }
```

}

Note, that `myTypeLifecycleStates` is autowired "service"/"business logic" bean.